# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892 throw error

Tags: reactjs, heroku, mern

I have deployed my react application in heroku. Build was successful. When I try to run the apllication I am getting an Application error. The error is

```
021-09-05T18:09:02.093946+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-09-05T18:09:04.858809+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-09-05T18:09:04.858836+00:00 app[web.1]: > photoshare@1.0.0 start /app
2021-09-05T18:09:04.858837+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2021-09-05T18:09:04.858837+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373833+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373849+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373850+00:00 app[web.1]: 

2021-09-05T18:09:05.373850+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373850+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './routes/api/users'
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373850+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373851+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373851+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373852+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373852+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373853+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373853+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:5:15)
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373853+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373853+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373854+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373854+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)

2021-09-05T18:09:05.373854+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373855+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373855+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373855+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2021-09-05T18:09:05.373856+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-09-05T18:09:05.385287+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-09-05T18:09:05.385456+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-09-05T18:09:05.388896+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! photoshare@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2021-09-05T18:09:05.388956+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-09-05T18:09:05.389019+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-09-05T18:09:05.389068+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the photoshare@1.0.0 start script.
2021-09-05T18:09:05.389117+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-09-05T18:09:05.393542+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this in your code `./routes/api/users`. May be you reference it in wrong way.

Or the better is to create and absolute path:

```
const path = require('path');
const yourAbsolutePath = path.join( __dirname,'./routes/api/users');
```

make sure `./routes/api/users` is well referenced relative to __dirname

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That is where the 'users.js' file is located and I have used this reference in my server.js which is the only one file that has this reference and the application was running so far so good in my local.

Comment: Great !, you can may increment vote of my answer. Good coding.

Comment: yeah but i am getting the same error in production but not in my local environment

Comment: can you try to specified path using path module ? path = require('path'); –